# Is it possible to unload assemblies or types from a Process ?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, process, applicationdomain

Well ,my question is a short question, What i want to know is just 
Is that it supported to unload assemblies or types from a process ? 
I don't need any code examples for this , I just need a short answer, 
Any help will be apreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot unload individual assemblies or types. Only a complete domain can be unloaded.